# wrap photograph into a circle in photoshop

Tags: photoshop

I few years ago (or longer) I create an image where I wrapped an image around itself as in the image attached to make a sort of world. I've tried to duplicate the process but missing the step of wrapping it around. I know that I squared the image and left extra transparent space on both sides. I have the original photoshop file but the layer that I need to know what I did is flattened. Please send me to a tutorial or maybe give me an idea what I did to create this effect. Pretty lame I know!!!
[Photo of barn windmill and house.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cRjc.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately this is the wrong site for such a question, as Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Also, tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic. You might want to consider posting at graphicdesign.stackexchange.com, but as written, this question would likely be closed as off-topic there as well (but I don't know their rules and guidelines well enough).

Comment: Look for polar coordinates

Answer (score 0):

If your image is landscape, this method will work a lot better.

Make sure the image you're distorting is square, but don't do this by cropping, actually 'squish' the width of the image so that it distorts it slightly.

Then flip the image updide down (180degs)

Then apply a filter: **Filter > Distort > Polar Coordinates**.

From personal experience it's important to make sure the center of the square has uniform patterns and color to it, this will help avoid too much distortion in the center. Although this can be achieved post-filter.